# assign a name for ajax POST request

Tags: ajax, post, request

here's a stupid question.
I've got this associative array that I need to POST via ajax request:

```
var ajax_data = "{email: "email", pass: "password"}";
```

now in my php code I'm supposed to get this data via $_POST[something], right?
my question is what's the name of the POST request??
and how can I change it???
tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look [jquery doc for ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

here is a sample usage of ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // type POST or GET
  url: "some.php", // php file that data send to
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" } // here is your data in json format
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

data format is really simple, it's format just like this

```
{ key: 'value', anotherKey: 'anotherValue', ... }
```

and you can access data in php like this

```
$firstData = $_POST['key'];          // this variable contains 'value'
$secondData = $_POST['anotherKey'];  // this variable contains 'anotherValue'
```

anything your write instead of `key` and `anotherKey` is key of your variable in `$_POST` and `value` & `anotherValue` are those values

Comment: tanx a loooot, I was going crazy over here. it's probably the stupidest question I've ever asked. hope none of my friends have seen. ;)